# Fastest way to XOR two specific bit indexes in two bytes

Tags: c#, xor

This is in C#.  I was hoping I could do something like the following.

```
byte byte1 = 100;
byte byte2 = 100;
byte1[1] = byte1[1] ^ byte2[6]; // XOR bit at index 1 against bit at index 6
```

However, I am currently stuck at:

```
if ((byte2 ^ (byte)Math.Pow(2, index2)) < byte2)
    byte1 = (byte)(byte1 ^ (byte)Math.Pow(2, index1));
```

Is there a faster way, possibly something similar to what I typed at the top?

Edit:

I had never heard of any of the bitwise operators other than XOR.  That's why the original solution had the bizarre Math.Pow() calls.  I've already improved my solution considerably according to my benchmarking of millions of loop iterations.  I'm sure I'll get it faster with more reading.  Thanks to everybody that responded.

```
byte2 = (byte)(byte2 << (7 - index2));
if (byte2 > 127)
{
    byte buffer = (byte)(1 << index1);
    byte1 = (byte)(byte1 ^ buffer);
}
```

Comment: Are you unfamiliar with the `<<` operator?

Comment: And not just `<<` but _all_ bit manipulation operators? `~` `&` `|` `^` `<<` `>>`

Comment: I googled it and am learning about it now.  Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.  So far, I think I've elimintated the first Math.Pow comparison.  I'll have to read it a bit more and think about it.  I'm confident I can eliminate the second Math.Pow with a bit more thought.

    byte2 = byte2 << (7-index2);
    if (byte2 > 127)
    {
        byte1 = (byte)(param1 ^ (byte)Math.Pow(2, index1))
    }

Answer (score 1):

Bytes are immutable, you can't change a bit of the byte as if it was an array. You'd need to access the bits through masks (&) and shifts (<< >>), then create a new byte containing the result.

```
// result bit is the LSB of r
byte r = (byte)((byte1 >> 1 & 1) ^ (byte2 >> 6 & 1));
```

The specific mask 1 will erase any bit except the right most (LSB).